# Alternative to custom hook call inside useEffect

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, react-hooks, use-effect, react-state

I have the current component:

```
const Timeline = ({ threshold, throttle }) => {
  const [films, setFilms] = useState([])
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1)
  const [loadMoreLock, setLoadMoreLock] = useState(false)
  const [
    localStorageFilmsCache,
    setLocalStorageFilmsCache
  ] = useLocalStorage('filmsCache', films);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchFilms = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch(
          `${API_PATH_BASE}/${API_VERSION}/${TRENDING_ENDPOINT}/movie/week?api_key=${THE_MOVIE_DB_API_KEY}&page=${page}`, {
            method: 'GET',
          }
        )
        const json = await res.json()

        if (page === 1) {
          setFilms((films) => json.results)
        } else {
          setFilms((films) => ([
            ...films,
            ...json.results,
          ]))
        }

        setLoadMoreLock(() => false)
      } catch (e) {
        setFilms(() => null)
      }
    }

    if (!loadMoreLock) {
      fetchFilms()
    }

    // Scroll handler fns...
  }, [page, loadMoreLock, threshold, throttle])

  // Return JSX..
```

And a custom hook:

```
const useLocalStorage = (key, initialValue = '') => {
  const [storedValue, setStoredValue] = useState(() => {
    try {
      const currValue = window.localStorage.getItem(key)

      return currValue ? JSON.parse(currValue) : initialValue
    } catch (e) {
      return initialValue
    }
  })

  const setValue = (value) => {
    try {
      const valueToStore = value instanceof Function
        ? value(storedValue)
        : value

      setStoredValue(() => valueToStore)

      window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(valueToStore))
    } catch (e) {}
  }

  return [
    storedValue,
    setValue,
  ]
}
```

I wanted to build a client cache for the API call using my localStorage custom hook. In the current context, I would have to use my custom hook (both the state and the setter fn) inside the default fn useEffect receives as parameter, which isn't possible. I'm quite new to hooks and I'm having a hard time thinking about alternatives. I could do this without my localStorage hook but that would be nice to re-use the logic I already got on it.
Thanks!

Comment: You can reuse your function without hooks. Hooks are important if you want your data to be reactive. Your sample doesn't need to be reactive. If you do want the data to be reactive, the current implementation is invalid since you will need to `useContext`.

Comment: What function are you referring to? useLocalStorage? It deals with state at the current state, are you suggesting not to use useState on it and simply getting the value from localStorage?
How would a provider/consumer resolve that?

Comment: Yes, `useLocalStorage`. Currently your `useLocalStorage` gets or set value to Local Storage. Your `useState` is irrelevant since you can directly return the value and store it in your other `useState`s (films, pages, etc). If you're trying to reduce calls to localStorage, this is still also irrelevant since it will load up repeatedly from `localStorage` for every component that uses `useLocalStorage`. You can test it out by inserting a console.log statement inside of `storedValue`'s `useState` init function. React context would call it once and provide it to all components.

Comment: I see it now, makes a lot of sense. I just used ```useLocalStorage``` instead of ```useState``` to persist the state. I wasn't trying to reduce calls or anything, I just didn't realize I could use the custom hook as ```useState```. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reuse your function without hooks. Hooks are important if you want your data to be reactive. Your sample doesn't need to be reactive. If you do want the data to be reactive, the current implementation is invalid since you will need to `useContext`.

Currently your `useLocalStorage` gets or set value to `localStorage`. Your `useState` is irrelevant since you can directly return the value and store it in your other `useState`s (films, pages, etc). If you're trying to reduce calls to `localStorage`, this is still also irrelevant since it will load up repeatedly from `localStorage` for every component that uses `useLocalStorage`. You can test it out by inserting a console.log statement inside of `storedValue`'s `useState` init function. React `context` would call it once and provide it to all components.